# Run application at VM start up in VMSS

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm-templates

I want to run an application when each VM starts up in a VMSS.

What I did is as follows:

1. Create an VM.
2. Put my application under C driver
3. Use Windows Scheduler to let it run during the windows start up (no need to logon) and it works.
4. Capture the image according:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/capture-image

5. Use ARM template to create VMSS based on the image I captured

I cannot remotely desktop to the VM of VMSS, so I cannot check if my application runs. The application will call a web API when it runs. I found the API is not called so I guess my application did not run.

Does any know the reason?

Comment: "*I cannot remotely desktop to the VM of VMSS*" - why not?

Comment: I can remotely desktop to VM now by configuring the inbound NAT of the balancer. And I found I need to restart the created the VM by vmss, then my application will run after VM starts up.